# Add delays between two successively executed functions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I would like, if the user calls two functions in succession, there to be some type of "delay" between the two functions, so that there is no interruption of a key press while the first function called is executing. Maybe something like a queue will do. To visualize what I am talking about, here are the functions I want to call, that, according to a keypress, draw its corresponding letter in the turtle graphics window:

```
def draw_H():
    # Draw the left leg of H.
    # The turtle starts at the bottom left of the letter, pointing right.
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    # Draw the bar of the H.
    # The turtle starts at the top of the left leg, pointing up.
    forward(-letter_height/2)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    # Draw the right leg of the H.
    # The turtle starts at the right side of the bar, pointing right.
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    forward(-letter_height)
    right(90)
    # The H is drawn.
    # The turtle is in the top right, pointing right.
    draw_space()


def draw_E():
    # Draw an E.
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    forward(-letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    forward(-letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def draw_L():
    # Draw an L
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    forward(-letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def draw_O():
    # Draw an O
    forward(letter_width)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()

def draw_W():
    # This function will draw a W
    left(105)
    forward(letter_height)
    backward(letter_height)
    right(40)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    right(131)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    left(141)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(165)
    penup()
    forward(letter_height)
    left(90)
    draw_space()        

def draw_R(letter_width, letter_height):
    # This function will draw an R

    slant_height = (math.sqrt(letter_width**2 + (letter_height/2)**2))
    slant_angle = (90+(90-(math.degrees(math.acos(letter_width/slant_height)))))
    space_angle = (180 - slant_angle)

    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_height/2)
    right(90)
    forward(letter_width)
    left(slant_angle)
    forward(slant_height)
    left(space_angle)
    draw_space()

def draw_D(letter_width, letter_height):
    # This function will draw a REAL D

    angle_height = math.sqrt(letter_width**2 + (letter_height/2)**2)
    D_angle = (90+(math.degrees(math.acos(letter_width/angle_height))))
    Second_D_angle = ((90 - (D_angle-90)) + (90-(math.degrees(math.acos(letter_width/angle_height)))))
    D_space_angle = (math.degrees(math.atan(letter_width/(letter_height/2))))

    left(90)
    forward(letter_height)
    right(D_angle)
    forward(angle_height)
    right(Second_D_angle)
    forward(angle_height)
    left(90+D_space_angle)
    penup()
    forward(letter_width)
    draw_space()
```

And here is how the functions are called to draw the corresponding letters:

```
onkey(draw_H, "h")
onkey(draw_E, "e")
onkey(draw_L, "l")
onkey(draw_O, "o")
onkey(draw_W, "w")
onkey(lambda: draw_R(letter_width, letter_height), "r")
onkey(lambda: draw_D(letter_width, letter_height), "d")
```

What happens right now is that when the function is called and the user either holds down/presses repeatedly the same key to the corresponding function, this happens:
[image: What happens right now]

^This is what happens when I hold down the key calling H. Also:

[image: What happens with R & H together]

^This is what happens when I type both R and H in quick succession. I would like there to be a slight delay between when these functions are called and then when they are activated, so each function will be able to finish its process, and the turtle won't go crazy all over the place. Any help regarding this issue is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you looking for [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.sleep)?

Comment: @senshin Well, `time.sleep` simply "pauses" execution for a limited amount of time. What want  is, if two functions are called by the user in quick succession, for the first function called to finish while the second waits for it to finish, kind of like a queue.

Comment: Hmm, there's a lot or code and much or it is irrelevant for the question... You should try to build a [mcve] next time. You should at least give a precise example, because Python only executes an instruction while previous one returns...

Comment: @R.Kap surely this is what a non parallel program does by definition.

Comment: @SergeBallesta  Check the now edited post, please.

Comment: @The man on the Clapham omnibus Check the now edited post, please.

Comment: @R. Kap I think you should call the second function at the end of the first function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of event programming!

Let's forget the Turtle for a while. What you want it that your program make drawings when some characters ar hit on keyboard. But while you are drawing something, you do not want that a hit on another character starts a new drawing. So what you want it to not enter a new drawing procedure if one is active. You just need a bit of synchronization.

As all occurs in same thread (and anyway, most GUI behave badly if different threads try to access the screen), you should actually use a queue to save drawing request and just queue the request if you are already drawing:

```
q = Queue.Queue()
drawing = False
drawingLock = threading.Lock()

def draw(x):
    global drawing
    q.put(x)
    process = False:
    drawingLock.acquire()
    if not drawing:
        process = True
        drawing = True
    drawingLock.release()
    if process:
        while not q.empty():
            do_draw(q.get())  # call the actual drawings here
        drawingLock.acquire()
        drawing = False
        drawingLock.release()
```

This `draw` function should be called from the onclick events and dispatch drawing to your actual drawing functions.

Comment: I tried this, and I imported the correct modules, but I am still getting the error     `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rohan/Google Drive/K12 High School Documents/Computer_Science/section_5/assignment_5a.py", line 452, in <module>
    drawingLock = thread.allocate_lock()                                        NameError: name 'thread' is not defined`

Comment: Okay, I imported `threading` and then put `drawingLock = **threading**.allocate_lock()`, but now I am getting the error                         `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rohan/Google Drive/K12 High School Documents/Computer_Science/section_5/assignment_5a.py", line 452, in <module>
    drawingLock = threading.allocate_lock()
AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'allocate_lock'`

Comment: I did not pay attention to the fact you are using Python3. In Python 2, you could use either  `import thread` and `drawingLock = thread.allocate_lock()` or `import threading` and `drawingLock = threading.Lock()`. But in Python3, `threading.Lock()` is the recommended way (old low level `thread` and been renamed `_thread` in Python 3 meaning it is now an implementation detail)

Comment: Well, that helped the program begin, but now, whenever I type a letter corresponding to a specific function, I get `do_draw(q.get())  # call the actual drawings here
NameError: name 'do_draw' is not defined'`

Comment: @R.Kap: you have to write `do_draw`. It is just a wrapper around `draw_H`, `draw_E`, ...

Comment: Are you saying that I should write `do_draw` in the `onkey()` functions?

Comment: Well, I just did this: `draw(q.get())`, but now, whenever I call a function to draw a letter, the program just freezes and hangs, forcing me to force close it.

Comment: I did it! Thanks for exposing me to `queues` in python! :D I will make sure to set your answer as the one that worked! :)